# Verify we're human: does not work

Tags: bug, captcha

In math stackexchange, I'm sometimes asked to verify if I'm human.

But actually it does not work since when I get the captcha actually I don't need to fill it. I just have to close the window and just click again on the button I clicked on.

Does someone know if it's a known bug?

Comment: How can we know that you're actually human, though? Did you cry at the end of Jurassic Bark? (Before Bender's Big Score ruined it)

Comment: i don't understand. maybe you didn't understand my question so I edited to be clearer.

Comment: It was a joke. In part, a reference to https://xkcd.com/233/ (specifically, the tooltip there)

Comment: Ah! Ok. I didn't get the joke. Thank you. But actually robots are not taking the decision to make posts on their own, so their owner would just have to remark what i've remarked.

Comment: Strange. In eight years on MSE, I have never been asked to confirm I am human.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I remember a thread on primary meta where the dev enabled captcha for unregistered users (very recently, due to a disruption caused by them).--> dunno if it has been lifted https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355670

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut   For me, it asks about me being human any time I paste in things without remembering to manually type a "........................" in the same window. For long answers, I try to write the Latex in a things.tex file I keep on my home computer. Also, I may paste in computer output. Seems fair to think the site is reacting to a post done all at once, without extra fiddling steps that a human would be likely to use.

Comment: It is true, that CAPTCHA allows (almost?) any action as proof that I am human.  So the question "is it a bug?" really means "does it stop automated spam?"  Your evidence does not answer that question.